# Porting WiFi network from NetworkManager to /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm trying to move a WiFi network configuration from NetworkManager to static configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`. The fully working NetworkManager configuration that I have right now is:

```
[connection]
id=MU-GAMING
uuid=eeabfcea-b049-4228-8d4f-f6e65b1f8447
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=MU-GAMING
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=[REDACTED]

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

And after disabling NetworkManager, in /etc/network/interfaces I have

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless-essied MU-GAMING
    wireless-mode managed
```

But when I try to pull the interface up, it won't bind to an IP address.

```
# ifup wlan0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/[redacted]
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/[redacted]
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=[redacted]
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=[redacted])
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=[redacted])
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=[redacted])
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=[redacted])       
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=[redacted])
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=[redacted])
```

This is an "open" network (no passwords) so I shouldn't have to specify any type of keys or anything in the interfaces file, yes? I am thoroughly confused, can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `wireless-essid MU-GAMING`
And not `wireless-essied MU-GAMING`

Comment: This actually answered my question and resolved my problem perfectly, thank you!